# how to escape special characters in php

Tags: php

I am posting this content in the Editor.

```
> <div class="faq"><ul><li><span class="q">What is a teest?</span> 
> <span class="a">A test.</span><div class="spacer"></div></li> </ul></div>
```

It is saving in the following format.

```
<p>&lt;div class=\\\"faq\\\"&gt;&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;span class=\\\"q\\\"&gt;What is a teest?&lt;/span&gt; <br />&lt;span class=\\\"a\\\"&gt;A test.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;div class=\\\"spacer\\\"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/li&gt; &lt;/ul&gt;&lt;/div&gt;</p>
```

So the output is not showing perfectly. I have added stripslashes and addslashes. Even it doesn't work.

What is the best way to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: And what did you expect?

Comment: I need to insert the same what i am giving in the text editor

Comment: What Editor you are talking about? And what code involved in that? I am sure there are nearly 1000 lines of code between actual posting and point where you watching this.

Comment: use html_entity_decode(stripslashes($yourstring)) on editor's output. Or htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes($yourstring)), maybe it's btter

Comment: @@col.Sharpnel: I am using tinymce editor. Code involved is PHP.

Comment: @Fero so, there is code in PHP that affects your content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's ugly..

You need `stripslashes()` twice, `strip_tags()` and `htmlspecialchars_decode()`, if you want working HTML code.

```
$html = '<p>&lt;div class=\\\"faq\\\"&gt;&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;span> ...';
$html = htmlspecialchars_decode(strip_tags(stripslashes(stripslashes( $html ))));
echo $html;
```

This will print:

```
<div class="faq"><ul><li><span class="q">What is a teest?</span> ...
```

Comment: are you sure about strip tags?

Comment: No, but if he want to remove the `<p>`. I don't know exactly what he wants to do.

Comment: Thanks floem.. I got what i want exactly... Thanks a lot

Comment: could you please tell me what is the use of adding stripslashes twice?

Comment: Your editor seems to add slashes twice (I think this is a bug).. So first reduce `\\\"` to `\"` and then reduce `\"` to `"`.